# How to create PostgreSQL trigger to insert value for another column?

Tags: postgresql

This is my situation: i have a PostgreSQL table used to store email addresses, sometimes the email address contains address extension like `user+ext@domain.com`, i'd like to create a trigger to store address without extension in another column.

- SQL columns: email, email_raw (without address extension).
- I tried with this function and trigger, but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strip_addr_extension() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.email LIKE '%+%') THEN
        NEW.email_raw := split_part(NEW.email, '+', 1) || '@' || split_part(NEW.email, '@', -1);
    ELSE
        NEW.email_raw := NEW.email;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER maddr_email_raw
    BEFORE INSERT ON maddr
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE strip_addr_extension();
```

When i insert a new record, it raises error:

```
SQL> insert into maddr (email) values ('l3+bounce@a.io');

ERROR:  function split_part(bytea, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT split_part(NEW.email, '+', 1) || '@' || split_part(NE...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT split_part(NEW.email, '+', 1) || '@' || split_part(NEW.email, '@', -1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function strip_addr_extension() line 4 at assignment
```

What's the problem and how can i fix it? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR:  function split_part(bytea, unknown, integer) does not exist

This error message reveals that the `email` column is of type `bytea`, which is normally for binary data.

Text functions will not work with binary arguments because they can't assume that there is text with a valid encoding (and which one) behind a series of bytes.

Consider changing the datatype to `text` or converting dynamically the `bytea` data to `text` data with the [`convert_from(string bytea, src_encoding name)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function.